# FlashBuilder Away3D iOS -

Tags: android, ios, air, flash-builder, away3d

- Flash Builder 4.7
- Air SDK 3.5
- Away3D 4.0.9 Gold
- Simulator iOS SDK (5.0, 5.1, 6.1)
- iPhone 3GS 6.1
- Android device in 2.3.6

I try make a test with Away3d in Flash Builder for Mobile (iOS, Android)...
I cant run my little teste in iOS Simulator, Device (iphone e android), BUT, my code run 100% in Air Simulator
I set renderMode to GPU, Direct and Auto, in all cases, only Air Simulator run the code
What i missed?

The error show in debug is:

```
Error: Error #3613: The native shader compilation failed.
    at flash.display3D::Program3D/upload()
    at away3d.core.managers::AGALProgram3DCache/setProgram3D()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/core/managers/AGALProgram3DCache.as:98]
    at away3d.materials.passes::MaterialPassBase/updateProgram()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/materials/passes/MaterialPassBase.as:363]
    at away3d.materials.passes::DefaultScreenPass/updateProgram()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/materials/passes/DefaultScreenPass.as:659]
    at away3d.materials.passes::MaterialPassBase/activate()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/materials/passes/MaterialPassBase.as:261]
    at away3d.materials.passes::DefaultScreenPass/activate()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/materials/passes/DefaultScreenPass.as:515]
    at away3d.materials::MaterialBase/activatePass()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/materials/MaterialBase.as:352]
    at away3d.core.render::DefaultRenderer/drawRenderables()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/core/render/DefaultRenderer.as:152]
    at away3d.core.render::DefaultRenderer/draw()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/core/render/DefaultRenderer.as:102]
    at away3d.core.render::RendererBase/executeRender()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/core/render/RendererBase.as:288]
    at away3d.core.render::DefaultRenderer/executeRender()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/core/render/DefaultRenderer.as:62]
    at away3d.core.render::RendererBase/render()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/core/render/RendererBase.as:252]
    at away3d.containers::View3D/render()[/Users/robbateman/Documents/fdt5workspace/away3d-core-fp11/src/away3d/containers/View3D.as:611]
    at Testes/update()[/Users/lokovarrido/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/Testes/src/Testes.as:41]
```

My code is:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    import away3d.cameras.Camera3D;
    import away3d.containers.View3D;
    import away3d.entities.Mesh;
    import away3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
    import away3d.primitives.SphereGeometry;

    [SWF(frameRate="60", width="100%", height="100%", backgroundColor="0x000000")]

    public class Testes extends Sprite
    {

        private var cam:Camera3D;
        private var view:View3D;

        public function Testes()
        {

            cam = new Camera3D();
            cam.z = -350;

            view = new View3D(null, cam);
            addChild(view);

            var sphere:SphereGeometry = new SphereGeometry();
            var sphereMaterial:ColorMaterial = new ColorMaterial(0xff0000);
            var sphereMesh:Mesh = new Mesh(sphere, sphereMaterial);
            view.scene.addChild(sphereMesh);    

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

        }

        public function update(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("update");
            view.render();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Adobe AIR Application Descriptor XML, under `<initialWindow>`, set `depthAndStencil`:

```
<initialWindow>
    <depthAndStencil>true</depthAndStencil>
```

Comment: thx... work fine with renderMode direct...
if i want use renderMode gpu? there any suggest?